# net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) error loading external js scripts

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from 'express';
const path = require("path");
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public/css')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));  
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public/img')));                  

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.render('index.ejs', {text: 'This'});
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Running on ${PORT} ⚡`));
```

currently i have this setup in my index.js page and my filesystem is setup like this

[File System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Bd6.png)

i am trying to link a button to an external script and have done so as such

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="../dist/button.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="test">click</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.ejs

```
const myButton = document.getElementById("test"); 

myButton!.addEventListener("click", () => {
});
```

button.js

i am getting the following error `GET http://localhost:5000/dist/button.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

i have tried to change the express static paths and tried to adjust the filsystem but none of that has worked so far and am still trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Where do you serve `dist` folder? But I sse that you server `__dirname` try `./dist/button.js` instead of `../dist/button.js`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski im using tcs to convert the ts to js so dirname is the dist folder and chaning it to ./ results in the same error

Comment: Try this combination `app.use('dist', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './dist')));` `<script src="./dist/button.js"></script>`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski still the same error

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me. I can't help you any better. You just have to know that paths in `html` files are processed by the browser and are relative to server, no to the file system.

Comment: If you expose the `dist` folder for static files, the script tag should be just `<script src="/button.js"></script>` The browser uses URLs, not file system paths. There's also no need to also expose the css or img folder, just use `<img src="/img/image.jpg">` in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issues and the main problem what in the folders structure: **Public should be in src** dir
instead of this (that you have):

```
- public
  - script.js
  - ingex.html
- src
  - index.js
  ...
```

you have to this

```
- src
  - index.js
  - public
    - script.js
    - ingex.html
  ...
```

And of cause we need this line in express configuration in *src/index.js*

```
app.use("/public/", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and finally the html tag:

```
<script src="public/script.js"></script>
```